# How to resize input box in UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput of Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput which is supported by Apple is very good; However the box is too small in iPad. 
I try to resize the box size to make customer feel comfortable to key in username and password.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAlertView` is a part of UIKit, to resize the box size, you might need to reinvent the wheel and create it by yourself.

Comment: I think u're right. I've searched and tried many ways and got no result at all.